# Selenium - Allure does not create screenshots

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, screen, allure

I have a problem with connecting screenshots in the report generated by allure using jenkins.
1. I have an interface called ListenersT

```
package Test;

import Test.resources.Base;
import io.qameta.allure.Allure;
import io.qameta.allure.Attachment;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ListenersT extends Base implements ITestListener {
    Base b = new Base();


    public void onFinish(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //screenshot

        try {
            b.getScreenshot(result.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Object testClass = result.getInstance();
        WebDriver driver = ((Base) testClass).getDriver();
        if(driver instanceof WebDriver) {
            takeScreenshot(driver);
        }
    }

    @Attachment
    public byte[] takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }


    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

I have screenshot support attached here

2. In each test, the listener "@Listeners ({ListenersT.class})" has been added to the beginning.

   @Listeners({ListenersT.class})
3. Still, I don't see screenshots in the generated report

[image]

Please help.